# How do I reverse-proxy with Nginx to a container inside Docker network made by docker-compose?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a few web apps running on my VPS. I have one domain, and I run the apps on subdomains using Nginx and server_name directives.
I decided to containerize my newest one, using Docker and docker-compose.
However, I can't reach this app with Nginx.

On my VPS, I configured app-client-proxy.nginx so that it tries to redirect to Docker IP with port that client-app (name changed) listens to:

```
server {
  root /home/dartungar/projects/app-client;
  server_name   app.dartungar.com www.app.dartungar.com;

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:8043;
  }

  # omitted certbot things

}

server { # server that listens to :80 and redirects to :443 }
```

Here's docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  client:
    image: dartungar/app-client
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8043:443
```

Inside `app-client` container I also have Nginx that listens on 443 and serves html file:

```
 server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

When I try to open URL `app.dartungar.com`, I get 502 Bad Gateway.
I know it has to do with docker networking - my guess is that I have to reverse-proxy to network IP, not Docker IP.
How do I do that? Perhaps I missed it in the docks - if so, just send me a link.
Cheers!

Comment: Use the host lan ip or localhost in the proxy mapping: `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8043` if nginx is running directly on the host.

Comment: @FrankNielsen thanks. I actually tried that, but it turned out Docker image on VPS didn't update with nginx.conf even though I rebuilt it on local machine and pushed it onto Docker hub. I deleted image, re-pulled it, and it works now.